Issue in the connection of Google Sheets with MySQL (string, username and password)
Could you help me to connect Google Sheets to MySQL, my localhost is without password so I can not use embeded application. I wrote that script, which unfortunately is not working and receive the following issue:

Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection
string, username and password. getDataFromDatabase    @ Code.gs:8

Could you please help me to debug, I tried several time without sucess.
  // Replace these values with your database connection details
  var address = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database_test';
  var user = 'root';
  var password = '';
  
  // Establish a connection to the database
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(address, user, password);
  
  // Execute a SQL query
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM customers');
  
  // Process the results
  var results = [];
  while (rs.next()) {
    results.push([rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2), rs.getString(3)]); // Adjust column indices as needed
  }
  
  // Close the connection
  rs.close();
  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
  
  // Return the results to populate in Google Sheets
  return results;
}



You can try using the IP address. Also, I suggest adding a constant/variable for the name of the database.
var HOST = '65.60.34.202';
var PORT = '3306';
var USERNAME = 'agustafa_users';
var PASSWORD = '';
var DATABASE = 'agustafa_barnes';
var DB_TYPE = 'mysql';

Then specify the database in the procedure that connects to the database
function runSQL(query, sheet) {
   var activeCellRow = 2;
   var activeCellCol = 1;
   try {
        var fullConnectionString = 'jdbc:' + DB_TYPE + '://' + HOST + ':' + PORT;
        var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(fullConnectionString, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        var stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.execute('USE ' + DATABASE);
        var stmt = conn.createStatement();
        stmt.setMaxRows(MAXROWS);
        var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e, e.lineNumber);
        //Browser.msgBox(e);
        return false
    }

